# Is there a way to make the "Code Folding" Stay Folded In Delphi 2010

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, code-folding

I absolutely love the **Code Folding** feature inside Delphi 2010. However, each time start Delphi 2010 and reopen my project the code I had peviously folded down is no longer folded. Is there a way to keep the folded code, folded when you close down the IDE?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I love the Code Folding feature and use it all the time.  Delphi will save your foldings if you set the "Autosave - Project Desktop" option.

Comment: @MarkF - Thanks. I saw in your profile that you are in Boston. I'm on the Cape. Send me an email rileymj@ (see profile).